# Pandas empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
-0.08150654489363679, 0.3262445628643036, -0.1983973830938339, 0.04597456371557881
```

and I am reading the file in like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\Basic_Stats\NDII\NDII_1984137_A_Annex.csv')    
print df
```

which returns this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-0.08150654489363679, 0.3262445628643036, -0.1983973830938339, 0.04597456371557881]
Index: []
```

I want to add column names to the columns like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\Basic_Stats\NDII\NDII_1984137_A_Annex.csv')    
df.columns=['Mean', 'Max', 'Min', 'Stdev']
print df
```

but when I do this I get this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Mean, Max, Min, Stdev]
Index: []
```

My desired output is this:

```
      Mean                Max                   Min               Stdev
-0.08150654489363679 0.3262445628643036 -0.1983973830938339 0.04597456371557881
```

something funny is going on when the dataframe is being read but Im not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the columns names as an arg to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\Basic_Stats\NDII\NDII_1984137_A_Annex.csv', names=['Mean', 'Max', 'Min', 'Stdev'])
```

by default it treats the first header row as the column names so when you overwrite the columns you end up with an empty df as you only had a single row in your csv in the first place.

Also it looks like your file has initial white space, you can set to skip these too:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\Basic_Stats\NDII\NDII_1984137_A_Annex.csv', names=['Mean', 'Max', 'Min', 'Stdev'], skipinitialspace=True)
```